# Processing second PApplet window does not update when method is invoked

Tags: java, processing, draw, papplet

I have the following code which allows to have two windows, in the main window when the 'k' key is pressed, must call the function `disegna()` of Graph and add the text.

But it seems not to work properly, no draw update occurs.

Can you give me a hand?

[image]

```java
int N = 500;
boolean flag = false;
Grafico graph = new Grafico(N, N);

void settings() {
  size(N, N);
}

void setup() {
  surface.setTitle("Grafico1");
  surface.setLocation(0, 0);

  String[] args = {
    "--location=" + (N*2) + ",0", 
    "Grafico2"
  };
  PApplet.runSketch(args, graph);
  grafico();
}

void grafico() {
  background(0);
  text("Main", 10, 20);
}

void keyPressed() {
  switch (key) {
  case 'k':
    graph.disegna();
    break;
  }
}

void draw() {
  if (!flag) {
    frame.setLocation(0, 0);
    flag = true;
  }
}

public class Grafico extends PApplet {
  private final int w, h;

  public Grafico(int w, int h) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
  
  void settings () {
    size(w, h);
  }
  
  void setup() {
    ini();
  }

  void ini() {
    background(0);
    text("Second", 10, 20);
  }
  
  void disegna() {
     text("Hello!", 10, 50);
     println("Hello!");
  }
  
  void draw() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a small `delay(10)` in `draw()` loop of Grafico `PApplet` makes it work!

```
public class Grafico extends PApplet {
  private final int w, h;

  public Grafico(int w, int h) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
  
  void settings () {
    size(w, h);
  }
  
  void setup() {
    ini();
  }

  void ini() {
    background(0);
    text("Second", 10, 20);
  }
  
  void disegna() {
     text("Hello!", 10, 50);
     println("Hello!");
  }
  
  void draw() {
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: but why does this happen?